# Can you put HTML in a global PHP function?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to create a .php file that uses a global function which has a combination of HTML and PHP within the function. And then it is able to be called in other files .php with:

```
include(Instructions.php);
GlobalFunction();
```

Is something like this possible? I've already tried to do this, but as soon as I include the HTML within the global PHP function, the page goes blank and nothing appears.

*****Instructions.php*** Below**

```
<?php
  function GlobalFunction() {
?>

  //COMBINATION OF PHP AND HTML WITH STYLE SHEET
        
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you will close the PHP tag inside global php function and start typing HTML, it will not work. Instead you can create a PHP variable and can assign HTML to that variable and then return that variable from functions.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? "The page goes blank" sounds strange - why not check for the error that is occuring?

Comment: Also, please check for other problems - `include(Instructions.php);` does not look like valid PHP code, as quotes are missing around the file name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this format in your file:

```
<?php
  function GlobalFunction() {
?>

  //COMBINATION OF PHP AND HTML WITH STYLE SHEET
        
<?php
  }
?>
```

Then in the file you want to call it in, use:

```
include(Instructions.php);
GlobalFunction();
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. I see no difference to the code given in the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

example:

```
function htmlcode($name) {
     echo '<p>'.$name.'</p>';
}

function htmlcode('Zack');
```

Output:

```
<p>Zack</p>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the Zack variable with a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it will only execute in php block code not in second php block code.

**valid**

```
  ?php
   function name() {
   echo'<b>'"name"'</b>';
   } 
   function name();
   ?>
```